# hook_form_alter and hook_user_presave are not working in a production evironment

Tags: hooks, forms, users

I observe very strange behavior of my D7 (7.39) prod site. I have dev environmnet (7.39) where I use `hook_form_alter`to change form submit function. I copied code from `user` module and added some custom code (changed welcome message and added redirect if $_SESSION['VAR'] set)

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() for user_register_form().
**/
function MyMODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

$form['#submit'][0] = 'MyMODULE_user_register_form_submit';


 if(isset($_SESSION['VAR'])){
     unset($form['autoassignrole_user']);
 }


}




//Custom register form submit function
function MyMODULE_user_register_form_submit($form, &$form_state){

     $admin = $form_state['values']['administer_users'];

 if (!variable_get('user_email_verification', TRUE) || $admin) {
$pass = $form_state['values']['pass'];
}
else {
$pass = user_password();
}
$notify = !empty($form_state['values']['notify']);

// Remove unneeded values.
form_state_values_clean($form_state);

$form_state['values']['pass'] = $pass;
$form_state['values']['init'] = $form_state['values']['mail'];

$account = $form['#user'];

entity_form_submit_build_entity('user', $account, $form, $form_state);

// Populate $edit with the properties of $account, which have been edited on
// this form by taking over all values, which appear in the form values too.
$edit = array_intersect_key((array) $account, $form_state['values']);
$account = user_save($account, $edit);

// Terminate if an error occurred during user_save().
if (!$account) {
  drupal_set_message(t("Error saving user account."), 'error');
  $form_state['redirect'] = '';
return;
}
 $form_state['user'] = $account;
$form_state['values']['uid'] = $account->uid;

watchdog('user', 'New user: %name (%email).', array('%name' =>      $form_state['values']['name'], '%email' => $form_state['values']['mail']), WATCHDOG_NOTICE, l(t('edit'), 'user/' . $account->uid . '/edit'));

// Add plain text password into user account to generate mail tokens.
$account->password = $pass;

// New administrative account without notification.
$uri = entity_uri('user', $account);
if ($admin && !$notify) {
drupal_set_message(t('Created a new user account for <a href="@url">%name</a>. No e-mail has been sent.', array('@url' => url($uri['path'], $uri['options']), '%name' => $account->name)));
 }
 // No e-mail verification required; log in user immediately.
 elseif (!$admin && !variable_get('user_email_verification', TRUE) && $account->status) {
 _user_mail_notify('register_no_approval_required', $account);
$form_state['uid'] = $account->uid;
user_login_submit(array(), $form_state);

drupal_set_message(t('Registration successful'));

$form_state['redirect'] = '';
 }
// No administrator approval required.
elseif ($account->status || $notify) {
$op = $notify ? 'register_admin_created' : 'register_no_approval_required';
_user_mail_notify($op, $account);
if ($notify) {
  drupal_set_message(t('A welcome message with further instructions has been e-mailed to the new user <a href="@url">%name</a>.', array('@url' => url($uri['path'], $uri['options']), '%name' => $account->name)));
  }
  else {
  drupal_set_message(t('A welcome message with further instructions has been sent to your e-mail address.'));
  $form_state['redirect'] = '';
}
 }
 // Administrator approval required.
 else {
_user_mail_notify('register_pending_approval', $account);
drupal_set_message(t('Thank you for applying for an account. Your account is currently pending approval by the site administrator.<br />In the meantime, a welcome message with further instructions has been sent to your e-mail address.'));
$form_state['redirect'] = '';
 }
  if(isset($_SESSION['VAR'])){

    $path = 'path/to/somewhere';
      ctools_include('ajax');
      ctools_add_js('ajax-responder');
      $commands[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect($path);
      print ajax_render($commands);
      exit;
   }
  }
```

And `hook_user_presave` to assign role automatically if $_SESSION['VAR'] set

```
   /**
  * Implements hook_user_presave().
  **/

function MYMODULE_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {


// Only assign roles if this is a new account.
if (isset($account->is_new) && !empty($account->is_new)) {
  // Get the existing user roles with the exception of the anonymous role.
  $user_roles = user_roles(TRUE);
  $roles_to_add = array();

 if(isset($_SESSION['VAR'])){
   // $roles_to_add += array_intersect_key($user_roles, array_filter(variable_get('autoassignrole_auto_roles', array())));
    $roles_to_add = array(5 =>'CUSTOMEROLE');
 }
      if (variable_get("autoassignrole_user_active", 0) && !empty($edit['user_roles'])) {
    // Value is a single, convert to array.
    if (!is_array($edit['user_roles'])) {
      $edit['user_roles'] = array($edit['user_roles'] => $edit['user_roles']);
    }
    $roles_to_add += array_intersect_key($user_roles, array_filter($edit['user_roles']));
  }




  // Make sure the roles key exists.
  if (!isset($edit['roles'])) {
    $edit['roles'] = array();
  }

  // Add in the new roles to override the current roles.
  $edit['roles'] = $roles_to_add + $edit['roles'];
}

}
```

Tested code was copied to prod. If $_SESSION['VAR'] set everything works fine on prod site. If not - user receives 2 welcome messages `Registration successful` and `Registration successful. You are now logged in.` which was originally in `user` module. And no role is assigned. I switched off any caching on prod and cleared all caches but it doesn't work on a prod.

UPD I turned on caching on dev and it still works. What can cause this problem

Comment: This line `$form['#submit'][0] = 'MyMODULE_user_register_form_submit';` tells me that you are firing your submit handler AND the default handler. As you said you copied the code from the default handler you may want to use `$form['#submit'] = array('MyMODULE_user_register_form_submit');`.

Comment: Yes, you were right about two handlers. Default handler appears in prod in `$form['#submit'][1]` for unknown yet reason. So I made following `unset($form['#submit']); $form['#submit'][] = 'MyMODULE_user_register_form_submit';`